# Equinox classloader deadlock

Tags: java, classloader, deadlock, equinox

On Equinox-based application deadlock appears sometimes on an internal classloader.
I've found the [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359535) on Equinox bug-tracker which describes my problem. But the fix is not complete for Java 6 or lower and the resolution for Java 6 is just a workaround: adding two VM options

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass
```

Also there is a [Sun bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4670071) for native `classloader()` and the fix seems to be incomplete also. So the workaround is the only solution at the moment.

So the question is: does anyone have any troubles or issues connected with this workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days of testing no issues were found with this workaround. So this workaround solved the problem.

Comment: I just hit this problem and your post was very useful.  If you find out anything more, or encounter difficulties, please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Been using those options with Sun(Oracle) based JVMs running Eclipse for years now.  Have never had an issue that could be traced to them.